# Does Marketo support Journeys?

Tags: marketo, journey

I'm curious in if Marketo has something similar as Journeys and Journey Builder tool in Marketing Cloud? Can we create in Marketo some graphical representations of marketing customer journeys.

If no, maybe you know some other marketing solutions that can satisfy our needs.

Thanks!
Roman

Answer (score 0):

Categorically the answer is no, but you could manually arrange a program for each journey stage. This leaves out the option for journey automation, journey analytics and the opportunity to personalize the entire journey. There are very few systems that deal with true journey management out there:
[Roojoom](http://www.roojoom.com) - focuses on B2C service providers
[Salesforce Journey builder](https://www.salesforce.com/products/marketing-cloud/platform/digital-marketing-optimization/) - has a layer of campaign management like you would see in Unica or RedPoint but it can work if you use their marketing cloud.
Kitewheel - Services ecommerce and online travel well.